# How should I continue this code

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to obtain the username variable from an external PHP script that is not part of Drupal or a Drupal Module.

For Drupal 7 there was drupal_bootstrap to load the required Drupal dependencies. However, after a long search all I found for Drupal 8 was a note that drupal_bootstrap is deprecated for Drupal 8.

And indeed, I get a

```
Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap()
```

when I try to call it after including as in

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www/html/drupal7'); // Define the DRUPAL_ROOT constant which is used in many places.
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/drupal7'; // Again, this is used in many places.
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; // Include the boostrap file.
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION); // Start things up to whatever level you need.

global $user;
echo $user->name;
```

So how can I use the Drupal 8 API from an outside script?!

Posted this on another forum and I got this code, but it just doesn't work, so I would like to know what's going wrong. I know that something's missing, but I don't know how to *echo* the name of the current user who's logged on:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_DIR', __DIR__ .'/../../drupal');

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();

require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/database.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/core/includes/schema.inc';
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking in the global $SESSION variable?

Comment: Yes, but there's nothing. In Drupal 7 I could get the session directly from Bootstrap, but since drupal_bootstrap() is now deprecated, I can't. Remember that I'm talking about getting the current user's name from an external PHP (not a Drupal Module or something, just an external PHP)

Comment: I found this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/196273/26823 but honestly, I would just use REST. You don't have to do any bootstrapping and it's pretty easy to create a custom REST resource.

Comment: @Ronnie I have no clue of how should I do it, even with the link you gave me. You say that REST is easier, but I don't know what it is, I've just heard about it twice. How could be this easier? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://drupalize.me/blog/201401/introduction-restful-web-services-drupal-8 It will allow you to create an API so you can use something like AJAX to get the information you need. I've played around with it a bit. I created an angular application with a D8 backend that could create/view nodes, upload images etc